# CPU overheating all the time on Asus gl703ge with dual gpu intel and nvidia 1050Ti

Tags: nvidia, asus, cpu, overheating, temperature

After I install Ubuntu on it, the cpus are always on high temperatures even with minimum cpu load.
I even removed nvidia drivers to force use only intels, yet it is the same.
At this time the load on each cpu is less than 10% from top cmd. But temp. are above 85 deg
[image: sensoroutput]

Below is the output. After I reinstall the nvidia drivers

```
Fri Jun 12 13:35:08 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.82       Driver Version: 440.82       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 105...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   72C    P5    N/A /  N/A |    318MiB /  4042MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      2000      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           164MiB |
|    0      2176      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          90MiB |
|    0      2531      G   ...AAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAA= --shared-files    61MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please do not add terminaloutput as picture, Just cp  it from your terminal and paste it here.

Comment: What's your CPU cooler. Is it stock, then definitely you need to upgrade it. Or I guess your CPU is thermal throttling, and It has nothing to do with ubuntu

Comment: @AdupaVasista Well I have dual OS. So in Windows it is quite normal and gets hot only when I play games. But in ubuntu it is just all the time as I mentioned. As for CPU cooler yes it is stock.

Comment: @nobody thanks for the suggestion. Will mind it from next time.

Comment: Can you update your question by posting the output for `nvidia-smi`

Comment: @AdupaVasista updated as you asked

Comment: I have done some edits to my answer. Do check the step by step guide.

Answer (score 0):

Under volting helps a lot when there is over heating (and by lot I mean A LOT). To be on a safer side, manufacturers supply higher voltage than required to the CPU (which causes heating), as at very lower voltages CPU doesn't work properly under stress. Under volting is completely safe. It will not void your warranty whatsoever. Under volting is basically removing the excess voltage supplied and giving the minimum voltage required to run the CPU smoothly.

Try `intel-undervolt` from [here on GitHub](https://github.com/kitsunyan/intel-undervolt).

[Here](https://miloserdov.org/?p=1932) is an article on CPU undervolting in Linux which I followed

Some terms in the guide might be deprecated. Refer to the first link for the deprecated terms.

Here is a step by step procedure with the non deprecated terms

1. install git with `sudo apt install git`
2. run `git clone https://github.com/kitsunyan/intel-undervolt`
3. `sudo su` and then enter password
4. run `./configure --enable-systemd --enable-openrc && make && make install`
5. close the root mode by typing `exit` and press enter
6. run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
7. run `sudo gedit /etc/intel-undervolt.conf` this will open a text editor
8. change the value in line 10 (in front of CPU) to -130 like this `undervolt 0 'CPU' -130` (recommended -125)
9. now save that text file and exit
10. run `sudo intel-undervolt apply` and then run `sudo systemctl start intel-undervolt`
11. use the system for some time, if it looks stable then run `sudo systemctl enable intel-undervolt`.

As of selecting the offset, I use `undervolt 0 'CPU' -130` in the `/etc/intel-undervolt.conf` file. As a beginner I would suggest you to stick to undervolting the CPU only.

To find the correct offset (unique to each CPU piece. Same CPU but on different computer could have different ideal offset) slowly  lower the offset by small values (I used 10), and at the point where your PC crashes, is the threshold. And set the final value to threshold - 10. In my case it crashed at 140 so I set it to 130.

The only downside (if you don't choose `sudo systemctl enable intel-undervolt`) is that you will have to apply the settings on every boot. I have created an alias with `alias us='sudo intel-undervolt apply && sudo tlp start'`. So I just have to type `us` in the terminal on a boot, and then I am good to go.

**Note:** the crashing of PC to calculate the offset is completely safe. It will not damage you hardware whatsoever.

**Note:** Any Intel CPU can go to -125 at least, above that comes the difficult part. If you want to take it to the limit, then only try increasing it step by step. Otherwise -125 will work just fine for any Intel CPU.

You could try to switch from NVIDIA card to integrated graphics card.

Run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime`. This is a software to control which graphics card to use. Reboot your PC now.

Run `sudo prime-select intel`, this will switch to integrated graphics card, which will lower the temps a lot. Reboot again and we are done.